Игровой объект, у которого есть свойство Rigidbody, медленно падает
Игровой объект, на котором есть свойство Rigidbody, очень медленно падает с высоты. Я примерно понимаю, что возможно проблема заключается в том, что второй аргумент Vector3 не должен равняться нулю, и если это так, то в таком случае, чем можно заменить нуль? Код представлен ниже:
private float speed = 10f;

private Vector3 direction;

private Rigidbody rb;

private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Movement();
}

private void Movement()
{
    direction.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed ;
    direction.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed ;
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z); // Строка, в которой может быть ошибка.
}


Нет никакой ошибки. Объект всё равно проходит через такт симуляции и приобретает силу, заставляющую его падать. В этом суть динамического Rigidbody, но если тело не должно быть целью симуляции и получать силу от иных источников, то оно должно быть кинетическим.

private void Start()
{
    rb.isKinematic = true;
}

можно и в Awake после инициализации rb

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
